# Windows not sizable and without caption

Tags: c, winapi

I want to to create a window **not sizable** and without caption like vista sndvol.exe 
[DlgSimpleVolume](http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/4871/vistasndbf8.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME style in CreateWindowEx and don't set WS_CAPTION.
Read the manual about possible styles

Comment: Disable the theme in the borders, no aero.
http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/2123/noaerobo8.png